# Push notifications within a Restful protocol for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, rest, nsurlconnection

I'm working on an iOS app which needs to maintain a connection to a web service.

I thought about developing a `RESTFul` protocol between my app and the server. 
But the point is that the server must also be able to push data to the app.
So I'm wondering if I can accomplish that only with the apple sdk by using the `NSURLConnection` and the xml parser provided...

To be more precise, is it possible to maintain a `NSURLConnection` for as long as the app is running and process data coming from the server without having to request it from the app ?
Do I have to send Keep-alive packets or something ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Have you got an answer to your question? If so, please accept that answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to send keep-alive packets or similar, because your connection will at some point have a time-out (you could of course just set a very, very high timeout for your `NSURLConnection`, but that's not the best idea as you would find it hard to know when your service had *genuinely* timed out).

That said, it is problematic to do what you're proposing on mobile, because powering the cellular radio takes up a comparatively huge amount of battery. Apple's documentation strongly recommends you keep network traffic to a minimum. The best solution is probably going to be doing what Apple do for push notifications - using a sockets to push your data over. This is quite a bit more complex than just using `NSURLConnections`, however.

Comment: If I understand you well, i should keep the `NSURLConnection` for request from the app to the server and use another means of communication for push notifications ? Because, for some reasons, I can't use the APN service and I'm wondering how I could have push notification on the app side. I also looked in the Apple sdk doc but I didn't find anything which seemed to be helpful...

Comment: Why can you not use APN service?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to have a RESTful interface between the application and use Apple Push notifications. Then iOS takes care of the underlying connection to the push server. In fact it keeps a TCP connection alive. All the communication to the server could use your RESTful services, including the registration of tokens that you need to send to your own server. This is a solution I have used myself and it works like a charm.